# Dataframe to SQL Server using Execute many from pyodbc

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc, bulkinsert, executemany

I am trying to load data from dataframe to SQL Server using Pyodbc which inserts row by row and its very slow.

I have tried 2 approaches as found online(medium) and I don't find any improvement in performance.

Trying to run in SQL azure so SQL Alchemy is not an easy connection method. please find the approaches which I followed and is there any other way to improve the performance of bulk Load.

**Method 1**

```
 cursor = sql_con.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True
for row_count in range(0, df.shape[0]):
  chunk = df.iloc[row_count:row_count + 1,:].values.tolist()
  tuple_of_tuples = tuple(tuple(x) for x in chunk)
  for index,row in ProductInventory.iterrows():
  cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO table ([x]],[Y]) values (?,?)",tuple_of_tuples)
```

**Method 2**

```
 cursor = sql_con.cursor() 
for row_count in range(0, ProductInventory.shape[0]):
      chunk = ProductInventory.iloc[row_count:row_count + 1,:].values.tolist()
      tuple_of_tuples = tuple(tuple(x) for x in chunk)
  for index,row in ProductInventory.iterrows():
    cursor.executemany(""INSERT INTO table ([x]],[Y]) values (?,?)",tuple_of_tuples
```

Can anyone tell me why the performance is not improved even by 1%? It still takes the same time

Comment: Did you ever try [`DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) using `if_exists = 'append'` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying to run in SQL azure so SQL Alchemy is not an easy connection method.

Perhaps you just need to get over that hurdle first. Then you can use pandas [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) along with `fast_executemany=True`. For example

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
#
# ...
#
engine = create_engine(connection_uri, fast_executemany=True)
df.to_sql("table_name", engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

If you have a working pyodbc *connection string* you can convert it to a SQLAlchemy *connection URI* like so:

```python
connection_uri = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)
```

Comment: when i use sql alchemy this is ther error which it throws.                                                        An attempt to complete a transaction has failed. No corresponding transaction found

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. If you require further assistance please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that includes a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things

1. Why are you iterating over ProductInventory twice?
2. Shouldn't the `executemany` call happen after you've built up the entire tuple_of_tuples, or a batch of them?
3. The pyodbc documentation says that "running executemany() with fast_executemany=False is generally not going to be much faster than running multiple execute() commands directly." So you need to set `cursor.fast_executemany=True` in both examples (see https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor for more details/examples). I'm not sure why it is omitted in example 2.

Here is an example of how you can accomplish what I think you are trying to do. The `math.ceil` and the conditional expression in `end_idx = ...` account for the last batch, which may be odd-sized. So, in the example below, you have 10 rows and a batch size of 3, so you end up with 4 batches, the last one only having 1 tuple.

```
import math

df = ProductInventory
batch_size = 500
num_batches = math.ceil(len(df)/batch_size)

for i in range(num_batches):
    start_idx = i * batch_size
    end_idx = len(df) if i + 1 == num_batches else start_idx + batch_size
    tuple_of_tuples = tuple(tuple(x) for x in df.iloc[start_idx:end_idx, :].values.tolist())       
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO table ([x]],[Y]) values (?,?)", tuple_of_tuples)
```

Example Output:

```
=== Executing: ===
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(1,11), 'b': range(101,111)})

batch_size = 3
num_batches = math.ceil(len(df)/batch_size)

for i in range(num_batches):
    start_idx = i * batch_size
    end_idx = len(df) if i + 1 == num_batches else start_idx + batch_size
    tuple_of_tuples = tuple(tuple(x) for x in df.iloc[start_idx:end_idx, :].values.tolist())
    print(tuple_of_tuples)

=== Output: ===
((1, 101), (2, 102), (3, 103))
((4, 104), (5, 105), (6, 106))
((7, 107), (8, 108), (9, 109))
((10, 110),)
```