# Export dataframe from Python to SQL Sybase database

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I want to export pandas dataframe to Sybase SQL databse. From here i found the code how to do it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082339/dataframe-to-sql-server-using-execute-many-from-pyodbc)

However, I have the following error.

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Sybase][ODBC Driver]Syntax error or access violation (0) (SQLPrepare)')
```

Could you help to solve it?

My code -

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as db
from datetime import datetime

#set constants
DSN = 'DSN'
input_table = 'table'
run_timestamp = str(datetime.now())[:19]
test_date_start = '2020-09-09'
test_date_end = '2025-08-08'
input_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'model':['aaa','aaa'], 'result_type':['a','test_statistic'], 'test_name':['b', 'mwb'], 'input_variable_name':['c','pd'], 'segment':['car','book'],
    'customer_type':['le','le'], 'value':[60, 0.58], 'del_flag':[0,0]
})
query = 'insert into schema.table (data_input_time,test_date_start,test_date_end,model,result_type,test_name,input_variable_name,segment,customer_type,value,del_flag) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'



cnxn = db.connect(DSN)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SETUSER MYUSERNAME')

for row_count in range(0, input_data.shape[0]):
    #1 method
    chunk = input_data.iloc[row_count:row_count + 1, :].values.tolist()
    tuple_of_tuples = tuple(tuple(x) for x in chunk)
    cursor.executemany(query, tuple_of_tuples)

    #2 method
    params = [(i,) for i in chunk] #f'txt{i}'
    cursor.executemany(query, params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a 'f' string, but forgot the brackets. It should look like this

```
query = f'''insert into schema.table ({data_input_time},{test_date_start},{test_date_end,model},{result_type,test_name},{input_variable_name},{segment,customer_type},{value,del_flag}) values ('?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'''
```

Comment: thanks. edited the question, 'f' string is changed to simple string